# How to render web content in a blackberry screen?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

In the past I have used:

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.BrowserSession;

BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browserSession.displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

in order to open up new web pages. What I am trying to do is to render web content in the window itself. That is I do not want the URL address bar to show.

Is that even possible and how do I get about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open web pages within the application and not in default BB browser, you need to use BrowserField2. BrowserSession invokes default browser which has address bar. You can not hide it. Here is the [BrowserField Sample Code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Create-your-first-BrowserField2/ta-p/495508)